# How do I close an image opened in Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a python file with the Pillow library imported. I can open an image with

```
Image.open(test.png)
```

But how do I close that image? I'm not using Pillow to edit the image, just to show the image and allow the user to choose to save it or delete it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

With [`Image.close()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.close)

You can also do it in a `with` block:

```
with Image.open('test.png') as test_image:
    do_things(test_image)
```

An example of using `Image.close()`:

```
test = Image.open('test.png')
test.close()
```

Comment: I always use the second option. Context managers are really nice.

Comment: @Brobin Oh yeah, with blocks are the way to go. And also one of the things I miss most when I have to use another language.

Comment: Using "with" I get an "AttributeError: __exit__" Error with PIL 1.1.7, which version do you use?

Comment: I know this a really old post but on my Mac .close() doesn't do anything. The File opens in the Preview and stays open after calling .close().

Answer (score -9):

If you create a PIL object you will see there is no close method.

```
from PIL import Image

img=Image.open("image.jpg")
dir(img)

['_Image__transformer', '_PngImageFile__idat', '__doc__', '__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '__repr__', '_copy', '_dump', '_expand', '_makeself', '_new', '_open', 'category', 'convert', 'copy', 'crop', 'decoderconfig', 'decodermaxblock', 'draft', 'filename', 'filter', 'format', 'format_description', 'fp', 'frombytes', 'fromstring', 'getbands', 'getbbox', 'getcolors', 'getdata', 'getextrema', 'getim', 'getpalette', 'getpixel', 'getprojection', 'histogram', 'im', 'info', 'load', 'load_end', 'load_prepare', 'load_read', 'map', 'mode', 'offset', 'palette', 'paste', 'png', 'point', 'putalpha', 'putdata', 'putpalette', 'putpixel', 'quantize', 'readonly', 'resize', 'rotate', 'save', 'seek', 'show', 'size', 'split', 'tell', 'text', 'thumbnail', 'tile', 'tobitmap', 'tobytes', 'tostring', 'transform', 'transpose', 'verify']
```

Comment: There is though, take a look at the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.close). I'm not sure why it doesn't show up in the directory of the object, but it definitely exists.

Comment: My Pillow(version 2.3.0) seems missing the close method, too.

Comment: I'm using pkg_resources to check its version: >>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('Pillow').version
'2.3.0'

Comment: In my case I was also using PGMagick so make sure you're not confusing the two packages if you're converting to PDF.