# UnicodeDecodeError using PIL module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am getting this error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

From this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image_name = "mypic"
count = 0

for filename in os.listdir('pictures'):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
        image_file = open('pictures/' +filename)
        image = Image.open(image_file)

        # next 3 lines strip exif
        data = list(image.getdata())
        image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
        image_without_exif.putdata(data)

        image_without_exif.save('new-pictures/' + image_name + str(count) + '.jpg')
        count = count + 1;
```

Not sure why, as this was working yesterday...

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to open the file in binary mode:

```
image_file = open('pictures/' +filename, 'rb')
```

Comment: This will work too, and is likely a better route if directly manipulating the file is necessary (for example [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)). Similarly, PIL.Image will accept any bytes-like object (such as a `BytesIO`) which _"must implement read(), seek(), and tell() methods, and be opened in binary mode"_ [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `open` is trying to read the file as text. You can resolve this by opening the path directly with `Image.open()`

```py
img = Image.open('pictures/' + filename)
```

This works because PIL does the related handling for you internally; take a look at its documentation here for more!
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open

Further, it probably makes even more sense to use `Image.open` as a context manager to handle opening and closing your image when done ([there's a good explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751501/4541045))

```py
with Image.open('pictures/' + filename) as img:
    # process img
# image file closed now after leaving context scope
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `open(filename)` function without any further arguments, you open the file in "text" mode.

Python will assume that the file contains text when reading it. When it finds a byte with the value of `255` (0xFF), it is confused because no text character matches that byte.

To fix this, open the file in bytes mode:

```
open(filename, "b")
```

This tells python to not assume it contains text and the file handle will just give out the raw bytes instead.

Because this is a common use-case, PIL already has opening images by filename built in:

```
Image.open(filename)
```